# Final cut auto split on black frames

Tags: macos, video, final-cut-pro

i'm new to Final Cut Pro X. I'm wondering if there's a function that automatically splits a clip into pieces every time there's a black scene.
It's quite common to cover the camera after each scene.
for example, this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vkjt5QR1lmU i would like that final cut splits it every time there's a black (in this case graey) frame.

is it possible?

Comment: I asked a similar question here, which you might want to monitor in case people respond helpfully: http://superuser.com/questions/692489/automatically-split-large-mov-video-files-into-smaller-files-at-black-frames-s